# Вызов функции из дочернего окна. Как вернуть значение в дочернее окно?

Tags: python, tkinter

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вернуть значение `list1` в поле `res_text` дочернего окна, а не в консоль, и при вводе новых значений очищать `res_text`.
И можно ли как-то более проще добавить фон для главного окна?

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

def program(num1, num2):
    num1_g = num1.get()
    num2_g = num2.get()
    list1 = []
    for i in range (1, 10):
        num = int(num1_g) * int(num2_g) * i
        list1.append(num)
    print(list1)

def window2():
    w = tk.Toplevel()
    w.title("Второе окно")
    w.geometry("500x300")
    w.resizable(False, False)

    w.num1 = tk.StringVar()
    w.num2 = tk.StringVar()

    label_1 = tk.Label(w, text='Первое число').place(x=10, y=0)
    edit_1 = tk.Entry(w, textvariable=w.num1, width=5).place(x=10, y=35)
    label_2 = tk.Label(w, text='Второе число').place(x=10, y=70)
    edit_2 = tk.Entry(w, textvariable=w.num2, width=5).place(x=10, y=105)
    btn = tk.Button(w, text="Пуск", command=lambda: program(w.num1, w.num2)).place(x=10, y=140,)
    res_text = tk.Text(w, width=10, height=5).place(x=150, y=0)

    w.grab_set()
    w.focus_set()

root = tk.Tk()

root.title("Пример")
root.geometry("400x200")
root.resizable(False, False)

#l_b = tk.Label(root)
#img_back = Image.open("*картинка*")
#l_b.img_back = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_back)
#l_b['image'] = l_b.img_back
#l_b.pack()

btn_open = tk.Button(root, text="Открыть окно 2", command=lambda: window2(),).place(x=127, y=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `И можно ли как-то более проще добавить фон для главного окна?` - чем не устраивает тот вариант, который у вас сейчас?

Comment: @insolor, устраивает, просто интересно было, можно ли как-то записать это по другому, более кратко

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такой вариант: не выводить результат сразу из `program`, а возвращать список через `return`, и возвращенный список уже выводить в текстовое поле.

```
def program(num1, num2):
    num1_g = num1.get()
    num2_g = num2.get()
    list1 = []
    for i in range (1, 10):
        num = int(num1_g) * int(num2_g) * i
        list1.append(num)
    return list1


def window2():
    ...

    def show_result(data):
        res_text.delete(1.0, tk.END)  # Очистка текстового поля
        res_text.insert(1.0, str(data))  # Вывод данных

    btn = tk.Button(w, text="Пуск", command=lambda: show_result(program(w.num1, w.num2)))
    btn.place(x=10, y=140)
    res_text = tk.Text(w, width=10, height=5)
    res_text.place(x=150, y=0)
    ...
```

Обратите внимание, что если вам нужен доступ к виджетам через переменную, то `place`, `grid` или `pack` нужно делать отдельно от присваивания в переменную, иначе в переменные будет записан результат вызова этих методов, а они ничего не возвращают, поэтому в переменную будет записано `None`.

Comment: Спасибо большое!